# When importing certain dependencies using webpack, I get 'Error: Cannot find module "."'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

Using a minimal babel+webpack setup and including just one external dependency (ansi_up).

When compiling, I get a warning:

```
$ webpack
Hash: f9bff237cfd206599eed
Version: webpack 3.0.0
Time: 119ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  17.6 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./main.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./node_modules/ansi_up 160 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module

WARNING in ./node_modules/ansi_up/ansi_up.js
9:20-27 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

And then when running I get this error:

```
$ node bundle.js
/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:93
        v = factory(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()), exports);
                                                                                                                                    ^

Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:93:65)
    at subst (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:93:143)
    at Object.webpackEmptyContext.keys (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:107:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:72:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:63:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/src/webpack-ansi-up/bundle.js:66:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Example repo is here: https://github.com/doughsay/webpack-question

What's wrong with this dependency that causes it to misbehave like this?  And is there anything I can do as the importer to fix this, or does it have to be fixed on the dependency's end?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm just using node here to clearly show the error; I'm actually planning on using the bundle in a browser.  The same issue shown here happens in the browser as well.

Comment: Are you running your Webpack bundle in Node? Why are you bothering to bundle at all in that case?

Comment: I think you'll need `target: "node"` in your Webpack config if you want that to work?

Comment: I was using node just to demonstrate the problem, I am actually needing to run it in a browser.  The same issue happens in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because Webpack can't figure out what to do with this library. This fix would be to ask the library author to follow the common UMD pattern. Current `ansi_up` is *close* but not quite right.

https://github.com/drudru/ansi_up/blob/29ce78cf55cc87e8f221fc0f28150fa293a9c3e3/ansi_up.js#L20

should not be passing in the `require` function like that. By passing it in, Webpack becomes unable to reason about what dependencies the module uses. Since Webpack can't figure it out, it injects code to trigger an error instead.

An example of a bettern UMD pattern can be found in https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/commonjsStrict.js

Note that `require` is *called*, but the function itself is never passed as an argument anywhere.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer even though I haven't been able to prove it yet.  Your explanation makes perfect sense, I'm just having a hard time fixing it and seeing it work.  Apparently the typescript compiler by default outputs this "broken" umd.

Comment: It's not Typescript, that module has hacked together their own build process with https://github.com/drudru/ansi_up/blob/master/umd.header

Comment: I know, but the cobbled together UMD header and footer were originally copied from typescript output to begin with.  Can't find a quick link to prove it, but I definitely saw the faulty output when I was messing around with compiling it with UMD directly.  Anyway, here's my proposed solution for the meantime: https://github.com/drudru/ansi_up/pull/42.  Thanks for you help!